# Youtube Data API: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded (with API key)

Tags: ios, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Error Message:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "errors" : [
      {
        "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
        "reason" : "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
        "domain" : "usageLimits",
        "extendedHelp" : "https:\/\/code.google.com\/apis\/console"
      }
    ],
    "code" : 403
  }
}
```

I have registered, generated an API key for iOS, set the bundle identifier, enabled the API in the APIs Library and I still got this error after the very first request I made. No idea what i'm doing wrong, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was escaping characters incorrectly in my request string. Not a very helpful error message.